# How to prevent creating data if other user deleted it's parent recently?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase's real-time database + Unity, and here is how I created a js function for the voting process. There are a few parts:

1. One of the players vote, and it triggers the function newVoteForDetected.
2. The second part is checking how many votes this contest has already.
3. The function adds votes if it's not enough.
4. If the contest has enough votes, the function moves its data to another node for completed contests and finally deletes the data to make only contests without max votes presence in active contests.

```
exports.newVoteForDetected = functions.database.ref("Currentactivecontests/{userid}/Voteforstamp")
  .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
    var userid = context.params.userid;
    return database.ref("Currentactivecontests/" + userid + "/for").once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      var votes = snapshot.val();
      votes = votes + 1;
      if (votes <= 3) {
        return database.ref("Currentactivecontests/" + userid).update({
          "for": votes
        });
      } else {
        return database.ref("Currentactivecontests/" + userid).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
          return database.ref("Completed").child(snapshot.key).set(snapshot.val()).then(function() {
           return database.ref("Currentactivecontests/" + userid).set(null);
          });
        });
      }
    });
    });
```

It works well, but the problem is sometimes it creates a new "userid" and "for" nodes after deleting by other functions/users. As you can see, I already use update instead of set

```
(return database.ref("Currentactivecontests/"+userid).update({"for": votes});)
```

but it didn't help. When and how can I check if this userid is deleted, so the function shouldn't update this "for" node and not create a new userid node for that? And If I understood correctly, I have to check if it exists **at the same** time that functions try to increment the "for" value - at the same moment, not in the previous function, because other users can complete and delete this contest any second.

Comment: You're missing a `return` before `database.ref("Currentactivecontests/" + userid + "/for")`.

Comment: Thank you, removed it from the end, so now it's like 
`return database.ref("Currentactivecontests/"+userid+"/for").once("value").then(function(snapshot) {  `

The problem still exists though.

Comment: You're also missing a `return` before `database.ref("Currentactivecontests/" + userid).set(null)`..

Comment: Tried with this return, it didn't help. It seems like firebase needs some time to complete the last two tasks:

`return database.ref("Completed").child(snapshot.key).set(snapshot.val()).then(function() {
           return database.ref("Currentactivecontests/" + userid).set(null);`

If another user triggers the first function (newVoteForDetected) during this time, he could also reach `return database.ref("Currentactivecontests/" + userid).update({"for": votes});` when actually the whole node is deleted. But still, it creates a "spoiled" node. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: I think your running into an asynchronous issue; code is faster than the internet and it takes time for Firebase data to return from the server. It would be advantageous to read [Return from Asynchronous](http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/). It's iOS based but he concepts are the same across all platforms.

Comment: Tried to read your link a few times but not sure if it's my case and how to implement it in js. :(
For example, a user wants to update votes, it means he triggered `return database.ref("Currentactivecontests/" + userid).update({"for": votes});`. But I don't want to do that when the node is going to be deleted by another function from another user which started a moment ago. How to stop that in js? One js example would be great, it's all I need for my game. I don't think there is something on the front end I can do, only firebase knows if that node is going to be deleted in a second.

Comment: I mean as I understood it, every time I call "then" - it takes time. So to make it simplier, even if I use something like `return database.ref("someadress").once("value").then(function() {database.ref("someadress"").set("newValue");`
The second part (after "then") could be incorrect when another function (maybe by another user) deleted "someadress" node at the moment after "once" but before "set"... How to check it for sure before "set"?

Comment: There's a lot of info an examples here on SO about handling asynchronous firebase functions. see [Asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bnode.js%5D+asynchronous)